# Scroll don't work in cordova emulateur

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, cordova

I created a mobile web application under cordova I have a button that adds data in a given database and displays (with reload in javascript) on the same page.
some of the data recover remains invisible because the screen size is not enough.
I try to make the scroll content, except that it's not working with scroll in css.
I changed the emulator but nothing changes.

how to make the size of the screen dynamic according to the number of data or how to make a scrollable div in Cordova webapp .

thank's for all.

in my index.html

```
<div id="status" name="status"></div>
```

in my index.js i reload the page afetr recupering my data in database

```
buttonAdd.addEventListener('click',function(){
        donnee = document.getElementById("donnee").value;
            if (donnee!='') {
                db.transaction(function (tx) {
                        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO LOGS (id, log) VALUES (NULL, "'+ donnee +'")');
                    });
                window.location.reload();
            }
    }, false);
```

and i load data in status div :

```
db.transaction(function (tx) {
  tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM LOGS', [], function (tx, results) {
    var len = results.rows.length, i;
    msg = "<p>Nombre de lignes trouvées: " + len + "</p>";
    msg += "<div><table class='table'>";         
    for (i = 0; i < len; i++){
        msg += "<tr><td class='id'><p><b>" + i + "</b></p></td>";
        msg += "<td class='log'><p><b>" + results.rows.item(i).log + "</b></p></td></tr>";
    }
    msg += "</table></div>";
    document.querySelector('#status').innerHTML +=  msg;
 }, null);
});
```

in index.css

```
#status { 
overflow: scroll; 
/*overflow:auto;*/
}
```

[screen shot of emlateur](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MmxNC.png)

Comment: Which emulator? Does it work on the device? What OS are you targeting? Can we see some code?

Comment: @lexith i test with iphone 4s and iphone 5s